# Lookup value in second table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables.

Table `Data`

```
ID  Item     Kvartal
1   Payment  1
2   Salary   2
```

Table `Kvartal`

```
ID    Kvartal_text Kvartal_nummer
1     Q1           1
2     Q2           2
```

I like to map `Kvartal` in table `Data` to `Kvartal_text` in table `Kvartal` by matching `Kvartal` in table `Data` with `ID` in table `Kvartal`. To get a result like `Payment Q1; Salary Q2`.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM Data 
WHERE Data.Kvartal IN (SELECT Kvartal.Kvartal_text 
                       FROM Kvartal 
                       WHERE Kvartal.Kvartal_nummer = Data.Kvartal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply `JOIN` the two tables and select the fields you want:

```
     SELECT d.Item, k.Kvartal_text 
       FROM Data d 
       JOIN Kvartal k
         ON k.ID = d.Kvartal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL Join operations for such tasks.

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Item, d.Kvartal, k.Kvartal_text FROM `Data` d

LEFT JOIN(
   SELECT Kvartal_text, Kvartal_nummer FROM `Kvartal`
) AS k
ON k.Kvartal_nummer = d.Kvartal
```